# Complicated regular expression help needed in java

Tags: java, regex, expression, uuid

I need to match the following variants.

```
annotation: 103810471047
annotation: 1038104710
ANnoTAtION: 1038104710
ANnoTAtION: 103810571057
Annotation: asdf1234-as12-as12-as12-asdf1234asdf-abcd1234asdf1234asdf12
ANNotation: asdf1234-as12-as12-as12-asdf1234asdf-abcd1234asdf1234asdf12
```

I am having trouble coming up with the right expressions. 
So far I have tried the following using two look aheads.

```
\b(\Qannotation\E|)\b((?=[^\w\r\n\.!\?$]{0,5}?)(?:[A-Z\d]+\b|(["']).*?\3))|((?=[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}-[\w]{22}\b)[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}-[\w]{22}\b)|((?=[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}-[\w]{22}\b)[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}-[\w]{22}\b)
```

But it doesn't seem to match correctly.  I need it to match anything that matches case insensitive annotation, follow by either a number between 8-12 digits or a hyphen separated word list with 8,4,4,4,12,22 characters.

It should return 2 groups. 
first group is the word "annotation"
second group is either the 8-12 digit,  or the hyphen separate word list with 8,4,4,4,12,22 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the regex : `(?i)annotation:.*?\s(?:(?:\d{8,12})|(?:\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}-\w{22}))`

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/VEMxzM/3)

Comment: What if between the annotation, there can be any arbitrary number of non-word non-return characters?  

If i understand this correctly, it captures the entire thing as a single group,  is there a way to capture it as 2 different groups?

Comment: @JettinYeh - Can you give me an example?

Comment: For instance,  annotation::::  123456789
                       Group  1           Group 2

Comment: Sorry, i don't have editing priviledge.  
But here are some valid examples: 

annotation:::12345678910
annotation    12345678910
annotation  ::   1234asdf-12as-12as-12as-1234asdf1234-asdf1234asdf1234asdf12

Comment: @JettinYeh - edited my answer as well as the demo. Check it!

Comment: @JettinYeh - Also, in your post, you mentioned that you wanted to "match" the string, not capture it. Please be more specific the next time around.

Comment: @JettinYeh - DO you want to capture only the second part or do you want the annotation part as well?

Comment: Thanks @TheLostMind.    I want it to capture. Sorry. 
i.e.  matcher.find()  --> matcher.group(1) is annotation & matcher.group(2) is the number or the hyphen separated characters.  

Annotation is just a place holder, it can be any string in a given list.  which is why i tried using \Q \E

Comment: @JettinYeh - remove the `?:` from all groups. Makes them *capturing groups* and you can use `group(1)`, `group(2)` etc